# sqlalchemy not honoring uniqueconstraint

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I have the model below.  I setup the unique constraint on the customer and the IP's in the table. I dont want to be able to add a new customer with the same name and/or ip's.  If I attempt to do that, I expect SQLAlchemy to error out.  Right now it is not, it is just allowing me to add multiple entries with the same IP and Customer name.  My DB backend is SQLite

```
class SubInterfaces(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'subinterfaces'
    __table_args__ = (
        db.UniqueConstraint('hub_wan1_public_ip', 'ip_transit', 'customer', 'neighbor_ip', name='unique_sub_interfaces'),
    )
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    carrier_vlan = db.Column(db.Integer)
    cust_vlan_ipsec = db.Column(db.Integer)
    cust_vlan_wan = db.Column(db.Integer)
    hub_wan1_public_ip = db.Column(db.String)
    ip_transit = db.Column(db.String)
    neighbor_ip = db.Column(db.String)
    user_account = db.Column(db.String)
    customer = db.Column(db.String)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    status = db.Column(db.Integer)
    location = db.Column(db.String)
    is_primary = db.Column(db.Boolean)

#### Add customer piece ####
    dict_to_add = {
    "customer": request.json['customer'],
    "hub_wan1_public_ip": request.json['HUB1_WAN1_PUBLIC_IP'],
    "ip_transit": request.json['PRIMARY_TRANSIT'],
    "location": request.json['LOCATION']
    }

    add_user = SubInterfaces(**dict_to_add)
    db.session.add(add_user)
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Have you added the constraint to your model after creating the tables?

Comment: We need to see how you created your table to help you.

Comment: I am using a standard `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DBNAME}'` and then a `db.create_app`.  This is a new table and new DB.

Comment: Try `insp = sqlalchemy.inspect(engine)` followed by `u_constr = insp.get_unique_constraints("subinterfaces")` and see if the list contains the unique constraint mentioned in your `SubInterfaces` model.

Comment: How about directly adding the `unique` attribute to a column? For example `hub_wan1_public_ip = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the constrains are not working, but as a workaround I am doing a count on the DB and if more than 1, error out.

```
#first check if a customer exists, if it does error out
active_customer = response['customer']
count_customer = db.session.query(SubInterfaces).filter_by(customer=active_customer).count()
if (count_customer >= 1):
    raise BadRequest(f"Customer {active_customer} already exists", 400, {'ext': 1})
```

Comment: The unique constraint in your question implies that all those columns at once create a unique key.  Given your question's unique constraint the values `(NULL, NULL, "some customer", "192.168.1.1")` and `(NULL, NULL, "some customer", "192.168.1.2")` would be considered two unique entries.  Did you mean you want each column to be individually unique?  In that case you can just set `unique=True` on the columns themselves.